# Error: unable to recognize "mongo-configmap.yaml": no matches for kind "ConfigMap" in version "V1"

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, configuration-files

I am following a MongoDB tutorial on Kubernetes, but when I create the configuration map, it gives me this error:

> error: unable to recognize "mongo-configmap.yaml": no matches for kind "ConfigMap" in version "V1"

This is the *mongo-configmap.yaml* file:

```
apiVersion: V1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: mongodb-configmap
data:
  database_url: mongodb-service
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version should be lower case.

```
apiVersion: v1
lang-none
```

You can run the below command to refer to the attributes.

```
kubectl explain cm | head
```

Or

```
kubectl explain cm --recursive | grep -i <attribute> or head
```

```
KIND:     ConfigMap
VERSION:  v1

DESCRIPTION:
     ConfigMap holds configuration data for pods to consume.

FIELDS:
   apiVersion    <string>
   binaryData    <map[string]string>
   data    <map[string]string>
```